# rmarkdown results = "asis" started adding "```{=html}" with html code

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

Previously the following code used to produce

```r
[1] "<figure>"
```

It now produces

````r
[1] "```{=html}" "<figure>"   "```"
````

I'm not sure when this changed happened. Am I missing something obvious?

````r
file_rmd <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
file_md <- tempfile(fileext = ".md")

writeLines(
'---
title: ""
---

```{r, echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
cat("<figure>")
```', file_rmd)

rmarkdown::render(file_rmd, rmarkdown::md_document(variant = "markdown"), 
                  output_file = file_md)
readLines(file_md)
````

Comment: Works as expected. Do you use the pandoc version from RStudio? What´s your OS? Perhaps update rmarkdown?

Comment: I'm using OSX Catalina 10.15.4 with latest Rstudio 1.2.5042 and rmarkdown 2.1.2 and `Sys.getenv('RSTUDIO_PANDOC')` is `"/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc"`.

Comment: The output when render is called includes ```/usr/local/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS file12622933cbe.utf8.md --to markdown --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /var/folders/48/q6ltldjs251000_wvjrdy_vm0000gn/T//Rtmp0QSKz6/file12621078df44.md ```

Comment: Interestingly `Sys.which("pandoc")` is `"/usr/local/bin/pandoc" ` which like the above output suggests that the system install of pandoc (`brew install pandoc`) is being used.

Comment: also ```$ which pandoc
/usr/local/bin/pandoc
$ pandoc -v
pandoc 2.9.2.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.20, texmath 0.12.0.1, skylighting 0.8.3.2
Default user data directory: /Users/joe/.local/share/pandoc or /Users/joe/.pandoc```

Comment: Ok, when I don´t use RStudio I get the same result as you. So the difference is the pandoc version between the brew upgrade and the version shipped with RStudio.

Comment: Thanks @J_F that solved it

Answer (score 2):

I solved it based on testing by @J_F by adding the following to my `.Renviron` file to ensure that the Rstudio version of pandoc was used.

```
PATH="/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc:${PATH}"
```